# sharepoint connection Libraries

Tags: libraries, connection

am new in share point, my task is to implement Connection Libraries and how to implement. what are the features are there. which scenario need to use this.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know whether you are talking about data connection library or something else. If you are talking about data connection library then here is a msdn link to get u started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772101.aspx.

Generally this library is a kind of document library in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 that enables applications such as Microsoft InfoPath 2010 and technologies such as Excel Services to specify data connection settings using external file and are stored inside this library.